# Show Teamviewer icon in Windows permanently - setting with GPO as registry possible?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, taskbar, teamviewer, deployment

I want deploy Teamviewer 12 as MSI over group policy. The silent installation works as well but the icon in the windows taskbar is invisible.

My target is on the client computer, that the user can see automatically the TeamViewer icon in the Windows taskbar without touch the setting from the OS.

It's possible over as registry word?

Comment: Are you sure teamviewer is actually running? Installing is not enough.